# Converting shapefile to raster: Character attributes

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, polygon, r

I've got a shapefile that I would like to convert into a raster, but the trick is that the attribute I want a raster version of is character data. I'm familiar with geoprocessing using GDAL (in the command line) and R, so solutions using either of those two are preferred. However, I have access to QGIS if necessary, and even ArcMap.

I'm using [this shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqen9y6xb4095zk/munisCrop.zip?dl=0). It contains polygons of municipalities in part of Brazil. The attribute NAME_2 is the name of the municipality, and I want a raster version of that.

I know that you can't make a raster with characters, so I created a numeric version of NAME_2 in R by doing

```
library("rgdal")
munisCrop.shape = readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="munisCrop")      # Read shapefile
munisCrop.shape$NAME_2_NUM = as.numeric(munisCrop.shape$NAME_2)  # Make new attribute
writeOGR(obj = munisCrop.shape, dsn = getwd(), layer = "munisCrop", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") # Save new version of shapefile
```

Values in `munisCrop.shape$NAME_2_NUM` range from 1 to 787.

I was hoping to then use `gdal_rasterize` on my command line (GDAL version 1.10.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.2) to make a raster version of the shapefile. Here's the code I was trying (separate lines for clarity):

```
gdal_rasterize -of GTiff -ot UInt32 -a NAME_2_NUM \
               -tr 0.0002777778 0.0002777778 -ot BYTE \
               -co COMPRESS=LZW -l munisCrop \
               munisCrop.shp munisCrop.tif
```

This completes easily enough. However, when viewing munisCrop.tif in QGIS, I see that the data range from 0 to 255. This is confirmed in R with

```
library("raster")
munisCrop.raster = raster("munisCrop.tif")
sort(unique(getValues(munisCrop.raster)))
```

0 makes sense, as NA values got converted to that. However, the maximum value of 255 is no good; remember, the maximum value of that attribute in the shapefile is 787.

I think I understand why this is happening but can somebody really explain it to me and suggest a workaround?

I've tried various options in `gdal_rasterize` instead of `-ot UInt32` (for example, `BYTE`), and the result is always the same. I've also tried rasterizing it in R:

```
munisCrop.blankraster = raster(ext = extent(munisCrop.shp), 
                               resolution = 0.0002777778, 
                               crs = projection(munisCrop.shp) 
                               ) 
munisCrop.Rraster = rasterize(x = munisCrop.shp, 
                              y = munisCrop.blankraster, 
                              field = "NAME_2_NUM" 
                              )
```

But that seems like it takes forever. `gdal_rasterize` is way faster (a matter of seconds instead of... indefinite), so I'd love a solution using that.

Answer (score 3):

`255` is the default `NoData value` in QGIS.

I am not sure, what exactly the problem is with the way you tried it, but you could use the GDAL Python bindings to do what you want. For instance the following script converts your shp to a polygon based on the attribute `NAME_2_NUM`.

Import the libraries

```
import ogr, gdal, osr
```

Open your shapefile

```
source_ds = ogr.Open("munisCrop/munisCrop.shp")
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
```

Create the raster file

```
pixelWidth = pixelHeight = 0.01 # depending how fine you want your raster
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
cols = int((x_max - x_min) / pixelHeight)
rows = int((y_max - y_min) / pixelWidth)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('yourRaster.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) 
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixelWidth, 0, y_min, 0, pixelHeight))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
NoData_value = 999999
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
band.FlushCache()
```

Rasterize your sip based on the attribute `Name_2_NUM`

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=NAME_2_NUM"])
```

Add a spatial reference

```
target_dsSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
target_dsSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
target_ds.SetProjection(target_dsSRS.ExportToWkt())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with the speed of the calculation with the function rasterize:

```
library(raster)
## Set up a raster 
#Extent
ext <-  extent(munisCrop.shape)
#Resolution
xy <- abs(apply(as.matrix(bbox(ext)), 1, diff))
r <- raster(ext, ncol=xy[1]/0.1, nrow=xy[2]/0.1)

## Rasterize the shapefile
#you need to define the the value(s) to be transferred (munisCrop.shape$NAME_2_NUM)
# or else the raster values will consist of each unique polygon id
rr <-rasterize(munisCrop.shape, r,field=munisCrop.shape$NAME_2_NUM)
# Plot
plot(rr)
```

Comment: Right, as outlined in my post I tried that, but it seemed like it was taking forever. That's why I hoped a GDAL-based solution would be possible and faster.

Comment: It didn't took forever. what machine are you using?