# QGIS: Multiply raster with shapefile attributes?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile

I want to multiply data from a raster with country-specific data from a shapefile.
Which is the easiest way for this?

I already found this post:
[Converting shapefile to raster: Character attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91772/converting-shapefile-to-raster-character-attributes)

Each country in the shapefile has 6 different attributes of interest for me. Do I have to generate 6 different rasters out of it, or can I create only 1 raster with 6 different bands?